# Cannot access any page in Magento 2.0.9

Tags: magento2, database, docker

For testing purpose I wanted to use Docker container with Magento Community Edition. I use alexcheng/magento2 from [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/r/alexcheng/magento2/). After configuration of database and successful installation of Magento every page inside this service is displaying me error screen.

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 688248154740
```

In app folder I've found file with that number in `./var/report/` It contains message given below:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:2057:"Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Theme schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Theme data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Customer schema: current version - 2.0.7, required version - 2.0.6
Magento_Customer data: current version - 2.0.7, required version - 2.0.6
Magento_Cms schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Cms data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Catalog schema: current version - 2.0.7, required version - 2.0.3
Magento_Catalog data: current version - 2.0.7, required version - 2.0.3
Magento_Search schema: current version - 2.0.4, required version - 2.0.1
Magento_Search data: current version - 2.0.4, required version - 2.0.1
Magento_Bundle schema: current version - 2.0.2, required version - 2.0.1
Magento_Bundle data: current version - 2.0.2, required version - 2.0.1
Magento_Downloadable schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Downloadable data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Sales schema: current version - 2.0.3, required version - 2.0.1
Magento_Sales data: current version - 2.0.3, required version - 2.0.1
Magento_GroupedProduct schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_GroupedProduct data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CatalogRule schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_CatalogRule data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SalesRule schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_SalesRule data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Swatches schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Swatches data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_GiftMessage schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_GiftMessage data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0";i:1;s:905:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 {main}";s:3:"url";s:7:"/admin/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

I've run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `bin/magento setup:di:compile` afterwards. Still I do not have access to Magento pages (including Admin panel).

**How can I fix that?**

---

**Detailed info**

Host distribution

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Host MySQL version

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Docker distribution

```
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
```

Docker Magento version

```
Magento 2.0.9
```

Docker PHP version

```
PHP 7.0.6 (cli) (built: Aug 31 2016 21:32:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your database using command,

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

After run this command need to deployment,

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Remove Var folder from root and check again.

Answer (score 0):

before doing this take a backup image of your container using below command

```
docker commit containerID/containerName  newImageName
```

let try this, in your log file it mention related to version mismatch in **module.xml**

> The following modules are outdated:
>   Magento_Theme schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0

so please find outdated module list in **setup_module** table then delete that outdated module from that list. Then run the below command in magento root directory of your docker container it will update setup_module table.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I hope this will rectify your poblem